# MySQLのMAXはvarchar型にも適用可能？

Tags: mysql

**下記のような「文字列を格納しているvarcharカラム」に対してMAXを試したら、意図した通り抽出されたのですが、たまたまたでしょうか？**
北1
北2
北3

**質問**
・MAXはint型にしか適用されないと思っていたのですが、varchar型でも使用可能でしょうか？

Comment: はい。ただし`北10`は北1と北2の間になるのでmaxにはなりません

Comment: なるほど。最大の文字列値とは、そういう意味なのですね

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQLのマニュアルに、文字列を与えた場合についての記述があります。
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/group-by-functions.html#function_max

> MAX() には、文字列の引数を指定できます。このような場合は、最大の文字列値が返されます